# intersection of non zero prime ideals of polynomial ring R[x] over integral domain R is zero

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let R be an integral domain. Then how to show that intersection of non zero prime ideals of R[x] is zero.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,f\,$ is in every prime ideal $\ne 0\,$ then $\,1+xf\,$ is in no maximal ideal so is a unit, so $\,f = 0.$

Comment: Can we prove this using localisation of rings

Comment: @user156736 You could, but why use more complex methods when such a simple proof exists?

Comment: Dear BillDubuque : I don't know, I think that's a legitimate question that shouldn't have been invalidated. Some students get out of control with such questions, but this particular one looks fine. Perhaps you would consider withdrawing your hasty dismissal of the student's curiosity? @user156736 Regards

Comment: Dear @BillDubuque : If you don't recognize that *Why do that when you have my proof?* dismisses the poser's request, then yes, you speak a very different language than I do, and there is little else that can be said. Hopefully the poster pursues the line of thought despite your admonition. Regards

Comment: @rschwieb To clarify, my question to the OP was meant *sincerely*. Namely, I believe that understanding the motivation for seeking alternative proofs can be very useful when teaching. Please try to view things from a more *positive* standpoint when there is ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If $p(x) \in R[x]$ is nonzero with leading coefficient $a$, then $p(x)^n\neq 0$ since
 the leading coefficient of $p(x)^n$ is $a^n$ and $a^n \neq $ as $R$ is an integral domain. 
Assume for the moment that the constant coefficient of $p(x)$ is nonzero, we have that 
$p(x) \not \in (x)$ and 
by a well known application of Zorn's lemma gives a prime ideal extending $(x)$ not containing $p(x)$. We can of course factor $x$ out of $p(x)$ to reduce to the last case, this leaves only the possibility that $p(x)=ax^k$ but then $p(x)\not \in (x-1)$, and the same argument proves that there is a prime ideal not containing $p(x)$

Comment: Easier: any prime ideal containing the nonunit $\,1+x p(x),\,$ does not contain $\,p(x)\ne 0,\,$ see my answer.

Comment: Sir as I am begineer in this paper so would you simplify a bit for me..